# Why every module $P$ is the quotient of a free module implies the existence of this exact sequence specifically?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, free-modules

Why every module $P$ is the quotient of a free module implies the existence of this exact sequence specifically  $$0 \rightarrow \ker \varphi \rightarrow F \xrightarrow{\varphi} P \rightarrow 0? $$ where $F$ is a free $R$-module?

Comment: $\varphi$ is the canonical projection

Comment: If $\varphi : M \to N$ is a surjective map of $R$-modules, then $$0 \to \ker \varphi \xrightarrow{\subseteq} M \xrightarrow{\varphi} N \to 0$$
is always exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $P$ is the quotient of a free module.  This means that $P = F/K$ for a free module $F$, and a submodule $K$.  If $i: K \rightarrow F$ is the inclusion map, and $p: F \rightarrow P$ is the canonical quotient map, then the sequence

$$0 \rightarrow K \xrightarrow{i} F \xrightarrow{p} P \rightarrow 0$$

is clearly exact.